# Найти две строки внутри родительской

Tags: python, строки

Есть задачка, в ней нужно в первой строке выделить две последующие, к примеру в строке `"player"` выделить другие две `"lar"` и `"pye"`, так чтобы получилось `"pLAyeR"` и "удалив" прописные или строчные элементы строки получилась одна из двух строк (удаление не нужно я так думаю). И посчитать пары строчная-Прописная/Прописная-строчная. Это сделать получилось, код примерно вот такой:

```
s, sub1, sub2 = str(input()), str(input()), str(input())
for i in s:
    for j in sub1:
        if j == i:
            s = s.replace(i, j.upper(), 1)
print(s)
# счётчик сколько пар переходящих из прописной в строчную и наоборот
counter = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if i + 1 >= len(s):
        break
    if (s[i].islower() and s[i+1].isupper()) or (s[i].isupper() and s[i+1].islower()):
        counter += 1
    else:
        continue
print(counter)
```

Теперь же проблема в том, что нужно подобные действия совершить со строками которые в принципе не слова, а набор символов, как в `"ababbaba"` надо найти `"abbb"` и `"abaa"`, чтобы было `"abABBaBa"`.
Пытался сделать через срезы строки, но получается большое ветвление, а хочется решение более оптимальное.
Прошу помощи!

Comment: Кто-нибудь что-нибудь понял? Я ничего не понял.

Comment: Слова или не слова - значения не имеет. Любая строка по сути - набор символ. И "слово" это только для человека, да и то не для каждого, а только для того, который может понимать соответствующий язык.

Comment: `чтобы было "abABBaBa"` - там могут быть варианты разбиения. а какой из них выбирать?

Comment: задача не понятна... вот есть строка 'abcdabcdabcd' нужно найти 'ab' и 'da' что должно вернутся?

Comment: @splash58 тогда выбрать минимально возможное количество разбиений

Comment: чтоб выбрать минимальное по переключениям - `получается большое ветвление` ^)

Comment: Мне хотя бы толчок на мысль в правильном направлении, как лучше будет разбирать такие строки, как сравнивать элементы и выделять в родительской строке в таком-то порядке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой клаcc Counter - как раз для таких случаев

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'ababbaba'
s1 = Counter(s)
s2 = Counter('abbb')
s3 = Counter('abaa')

if s1 - (s2 + s3): # останется не пустой словарь
    print('останутся лишние символы')

r = ''
for c in s:
    if c in s2:          # если символ из первой подстроки
        s2 -= Counter(c) # убираем символ из Counter'а
        r += c           # добавляем символ в результат 
    elif c in s3:        # если из второй - повышаем регистр
        s3 -= Counter(c)
        r += c.upper()
    else: 
        pass              # лишние символы, я их просто пропускаю 

print(r)

count = 0
for c1, c2 in zip(r[:-1], r[1:]):   # будем сравнивать предыдущий символ со следующим
    if c1.islower() ^ c2.islower(): # если было изменение регистра
        count += 1
print(count)
```